# Intent clashes with the Google Adapter

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Any questions that are general seems to quit the actions and provides a result from the Google Assistant itself. The sample utterances are given below:

Check my calendar / Check my emails / What is covid

Have anyone faced this issue before and have a potential solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are handling those questions using a Fallback Intent. A recent change with how Actions on Google works means that the Assistant will close your Action and [handle the user statement itself](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/intents#no-match_yielding) under these conditions:

- You are handling it through a Fallback Intent in Dialogflow or through a No Match Intent in Action Builder *and*
- The phrase is one that the Assistant can handle itself

You don't get any indication that it is doing so.

To work around this problem, you should use an Intent that matches a phrase with the the `@sys.any` type in Dialogflow or an intent that accepts "free form text" using Action Builder.